# How to forward one port to another (on the same machine)?

Tags: port-forwarding, nat

A machine (M) is behind a NAT.

Port X is forwarded through, and available to the internet.

My application wants to connect to port Y.

How to I configure M to forward incoming data on port X to port Y?

Comment: That's unclear to me. Are you talking about TCP ports? If your application (is that application on another machine across the internet?) wants to connect to port Y, how is _forwarding incoming data on port X to port Y on M_ going to help? Do you mean to say that your application on M can only listen on port Y instead? What do you mean by _Port X is forwarded through, and available to the internet_?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are talking about redirecting from the same machine, if so, you could try with iptables,

```
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport X -j REDIRECT --to-ports Y
```

Comment: That sounds right. If my question is unclear on that point, please suggest an improvement. :) I'll give this a try and report back.